# Google Sheets API v4 js client Authentication - Error 400

Tags: javascript, nginx, google-sheets-api

The problem relates to **Google API Javascript client** (still in beta since 2014 ?)

More specifically it relates to **sheets V4 API**

I adapted the browser-side [auth sample](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/samples/authSample.html) to work with this API

I tested it with the **calendar v3 API** and it works fine all the time

The page is served by full updated debian/jessie **nginx** (default install) on my own domain http port 80 (no proxy)

**Api Key** and **Client Id** are well set as well as the **Origin URL**

1. the call to `gapi.auth.authorize` succeeds all the time
2. the call to `gapi.client.load` fails **intermittently**

It works well **once** and then fails ~10 times when I refresh the page

Vice-versa if I code a retry loop, it fails ~10 times (always same) before working

```
error:Object
code:400
message:"Bad request: Origin doesn't match Host for XD3."
status:"INVALID_ARGUMENT"
```

The error occurs during this http api **discovery** call :

```
https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/sheets/v4/rest?fields=kind%2Cname%2Cversion%2CrootUrl%2CservicePath%2Cresources%2Cparameters%2Cmethods&pp=0&key=<my api key>
```

Any idea
Thanks

Comment: tested with Chrome and Chromium (apt updated)

Comment: same problem with Iceweasel

Comment: works fine all the time when invoked via the API Explorer with same scope and API key